# Mysql ORDER BY COUNT(* ) get the oldest row

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Can you help me? I would like to

1) Check whether the id from tb_pre_sale is not present on column seler_0 OR is present but not duplicated at least 2 times

2) Get the oldest one

Thank you!

```
 SELECT DISTINCT seller_0 
 FROM tb_pre_sale 
 WHERE seller_0 !=? 
 GROUP BY id 
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) < ? DESC
```

Comment: what defines oldest ?

Comment: the oldest row @AbhikChakraborty. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly by providing table data and result expected.

Comment: Yes but sql does not have any row number to mark a row as old or new unless there is a column that defines it like the primary key or timestamp etc

Comment: Thanks @AbhikChakraborty the primary key is the ID

Comment: `"SELECT DISTINCT seller_0 FROM tb_pre_sale WHERE seller_0 !=? ORDER BY seller_0 DESC"`

Comment: Thanks @DoubleH I need the count(*) < ?  too

Comment: if id is primary key then doing a group by id will eventually returns everything, so you need to define the query logic. Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: tks @AbhikChakraborty! The expected result is to get the oldest seller_0 that hasn't 2 referrals yet (count(*) < ?)

Comment: Please modify your question to make it clearer, rather than adding notes in the comments.

Comment: thanks @rghome! I have just changed

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT seller_0 
 FROM tb_pre_sale 
 WHERE seller_0 !=? 
 GROUP BY  seller_0 
 HAVING COUNT(*) < ? ORDER BY seller_0 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @DoubleH! I think it is something like this